# jQuery validation: inputs disappearing after all pass verification

Tags: jquery-plugins, validation

Unable to figure this one out...

In the below form, all of the inputs disappear as soon as validation passes on all of them, leaving nothing but the submit button visible.

For example, if I click "submit" on this form before completion, all unfinished fields are given the ".incomplete" error class to mark them incorrect. If I then go through the inputs one by one and complete them, the error class disappears. But as soon as the last-remaining input is completed and the error class is removed, all of the inputs disappear leaving just "submit".

I can tell it has something to do with the .incomplete CSS class, which is applied whenever the user clicks "submit" without having all fields completed properly. I can't figure out what is causing this behavior however. Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated! Sorry for the length of his code snippet but I figure too much information is better than not enough in this case.

Validation rules:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("#form").validate({
            errorLabelContainer: ".textbox",
            keyup: false,
            onfocusout: false,
            onclick: false,
            errorElement: "input",
            errorClass: "incomplete",
            rules: {
                organization: {
                    defaultInvalid: true,
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                    },
                firstname: {
                    defaultInvalid: true,
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                    },
                lastname: {
                    defaultInvalid: true,
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                    },
                email: {
                    defaultInvalid: true,
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                    },
                phone: {
                    defaultInvalid: true,
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10,
                    },
            },
        });
   });
```

Form HTML:

```
<div id="form">
    <div id="form_title">REQUEST INFO</div>
    <form id="form" name="form_container" action="#">
        <!-- fields -->
        <input id="organization" class="textbox" type="text" name="organization" minlength="2" value="Organization"/>
        <input id="firstname" class="textbox"  type="text" name="firstname" minlength="2" value="First Name"/>
        <input id="lastname" class="textbox"  type="text"  name="lastname" minlength="2" value="Last Name"/>
        <input id="email" class="textbox"  type="text" name="email" value="Email"/>
        <input id="phone" class="textbox"  type="text" name="phone" value="Phone"/>
        <!-- submit button -->
        <input id="button" name="submit" class="button" type="submit" value="submit"> 
    </form>
</div>
```

I'm using version 1.9 of the jQuery validation plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, have you added custom method

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("defaultInvalid", function(value, element) 
{
    return !(element.value == element.defaultValue);
});
```

Then correct your validation JS, you have extra commas at the bottom

```
(document).ready(function() {
       $("#form").validate({
            errorLabelContainer: ".textbox",
            keyup: false,
            onfocusout: false,
            onclick: false,
            errorElement: "input",
            errorClass: "incomplete",
            rules: {
                organization: {
                    defaultInvalid: true,
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                    },
                firstname: {
                    defaultInvalid: true,
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                    },
                lastname: {
                    defaultInvalid: true,
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2
                    },
                email: {
                    defaultInvalid: true,
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                    },
                phone: {
                    defaultInvalid: true,
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 10
                }
            }
        });
   });
```

Also i suggest you to try this way:

```
$('#Form').validate({           
            onchange: false,            
            errorLabelContainer: $('.error-container'),
            wrapper: "p",
                    rules: { ...//specify rules here }
});
```

Comment: I changed the class name from "textbox" to "inputfield" and the behavior remains. Thanks for looking into it though. I'm certainly a novice with jquery validation, so I may have caused a few conflicts.

Comment: You are correct however. By removing the "errorLabelContainer" rule, the problem is solved. That's how I was controlling the appearance of my error message so I get duplicate fields now, but it definitely helps to isolate the cause.

Comment: For anyone else reading this, the following was the solution thanks to Divide by Zero: Removing errorLabelContainer and adding " wrapper: ".form", "